# Adjust size of two dynamic elements to match height

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm trying to increase the size of the `ion-slide` and the `img` to match each other.

I'm trying to do this using CSS, but I'm not managing to increase the size of the two together.

**HTML:**

```
<ion-view view-title="Prefeitura Municipal">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
            </button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>

  <ion-content>

            <ion-slide-box>

             <ion-slide>
                <div class = "box boxImagem">
                   <img ng-src="img/Boletos.jpg" class="minha-imagem">
                </div>
             </ion-slide>

             <ion-slide>
                <div class = "box boxImagem2">
                   <img  ng-src="img/Arraiá.jpg" class="minha-imagem">
                </div>
             </ion-slide>

             <ion-slide>
                <div class = "box boxImagem3">
                   <img ng-src="img/Alimentação.jpg" class="minha-imagem">
                </div>
             </ion-slide>

          </ion-slide-box>

          <div>
            <div class="row icon-row">
                <ion-item class="col text-center">
                  <img class="full-image" src="img/capitol-building.png"></img>
                  <br>Prefeitura
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item class="col text-center">
                  <img class="full-image" src="img/leader-with-loudspeaker.png" ui-sref="app.principal"></img>
                  <br>Ouvidoria<br>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item class="col text-center">
                  <img class="full-image" src="img/earth-pictures.png"></img>
                  <br>Turismo<br>
                </ion-item>
            </div>
            <div class="row icon-row">
                <ion-item class="col text-center">
                  <img class="full-image" src="img/college-graduation.png"></img>
                  <br>Educação <br>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item class="col text-center">
                  <img class="full-image" src="img/doctor-stethoscope.png"></img>
                  <br>Saúde
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item class="col text-center">
                  <img class="full-image" src="img/bus-service.png"></img>
                  <br>Serviços<br>Públicos
                </ion-item>
                <!-- <ion-item class="col text-center">
                  <a class="botao button button-positive" href="#/app/site">Icon</a>
                  <br>Site
                </ion-item> -->
            </div> 
        </div>

    </ion-content>
    <div class="bar bar-footer bar-balanced">
      <button class="button icon ion-android-home">Inicio</button>
      <h1 class="title">Prefeitura</h1>
      <button class="button icon ion-earth pull-right">Site</button>
    </div>
</ion-view>
```

**CSS**

```
boxImgem, .boxImagem2, .boxImagem3{
           width: 100%;
           height: 100%;

        }
        .minha-imagem{
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0px 0px 0;
        }
```

Comment: make this a working snippet

Comment: What? I did not understand @DCR

Comment: it's easier for someone to work on your code if you provide a working snippet.  press ctrl m when you are asking your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the width is set via JavaScript and thus will overwrite the css rules.
Also it's easier to help if you use a service such as codepen to create a working demo of your code

Comment: Thank you very much, I was able to do testing on several cell phone screens.  Next time I put the code in codepen, I had never used it to help to post doubts, thanks a lot for the tip.